# How to make a customizable 3D character with maya for a flash game

Tags: 3d, flash, character, maya, editors

i'm working in a 3d flash role-playing game with alternativa 3d engine.

My game requires the main character to be customizable, for example, the player must be able to add a mustache, a hat, a tie, change colors of sking, clothing, etc, to the character.

How am i able to do that?.

(I'm using maya for modeling.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does alternative support skeletal animation?

Comment: yes, it does support skeletal animation.

Comment: If your engine supports skeletal-animation and bones, these answers should help you: [How do you make a customizable 3D character with animation in iOS?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17357/how-do-you-make-a-customizable-3d-character-with-animation-in-ios) and [How do you add equipment to a 3D character model using XNA/Blender?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13762/how-do-you-add-equipment-to-a-3d-character-model-using-xna-blender/13766#13766).

Answer (score 1):

If your 3d engine supports a scene graph, some scene graphs will have a node called a switch node.  This can be used to switch between different types of geometry.  So, you could put a switch node above the lip and switch between a mustache and no geometry (an empty node in the switch).
For clothing and skin tone, you might be able to do something similar with switch nodes at the texture level.  Not sure though.

Comment: I've never heard of a "switch node" and don't see why you need some special node for switching geometry; why can't you do this with any other node? Otherwise, I agree with this answer!

Comment: You can do the same thing by finding the node in the scene graph that you want to attach the new node to.  Switch nodes simply encapsulate that behavior for you.

Comment: I still dispute that scene graphs "usually will have a node called a switch node." Personally I think this answer would be better reworded to not muddy the waters with this term "switch nodes" and simply explain the underlying concept. Does Alternativa support these switch nodes?

Comment: i have no idea if alternativa3d support this "switch nodes". Never heard of them before. i've got to make some research.

Comment: Switch nodes are used in the Gamebryo (http://www.gamebryo.com/) rendering system which is a commercial product.  You can download the free version which is called Wild Magic - http://www.geometrictools.com/.  So, there's at least one credible source which uses switch nodes.